# I want show the first sub category when user click on main category

Tags: php, wordpress

create one custom post type..

I have many category and sub category...

```
category first
 -first sub cat
  --second sub cat
   ---sub cat1
   ---sub cat2
  --third sub cat
   --- sub cat1
   --- sub cat3
```

this is category structure...

when user click on the category first at that time see only first sub cat and then user click on the first sub cat at that time see only second and third sub cat in archive page....

```
<?php
$queried_object = get_queried_object();
$term_id = $queried_object->term_id;;
$args=array(
    'child_of' => $term_id,
    'depth' => '1',
    'taxonomy'      => 'product-category',
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);
$categories=get_categories($args);
//print_r($categories);
?>
              <?php
            // Start the Loop.
            foreach($categories as $category) {
                 ?>
              <div class="kkp">
                <?php
                //  echo '<a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a>'; echo "<br>";

$product_listing_image =  get_field('product_listing_image', the_permalink());
$kpimg = $product_listing_image['sizes']['pro-img'];    
                 ?>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-3"> 
              <?php if($kpimg != '') { ?>
              <img src="<?php echo $kpimg; ?>" alt="" class="img-responsive">
              <?php } else { ?> <img src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/images/large_noImage.gif" alt="" class="img-responsive"> <?php } ?>
                <div class="venue_hire_text">
                  <h2><a href="<?php echo  get_category_link( $category->term_id ); ?>" title="<?php  sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ); ?>" ><?php echo $category->name; ?></a></h2>
                </div>
              </div>
              <?php
            }
        ?>
            </div>
```

Comment: <?php $queried_object = get_queried_object();
$term_id = $queried_object->term_id;;
$args=array(
    'child_of' => $term_id,
 'depth' => '1',
 'taxonomy'      => 'product-category',
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);
$categories=get_categories($args);
//print_r($categories);
?>              <?php
   // Start the Loop.
   foreach($categories as $category) { ?> <h2><a href="<?php echo  get_category_link( $category->term_id ); ?>" title="<?php  sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ); ?>" ><?php echo $category->name; ?></a></h2>}

Comment: better you add this code to your question

Comment: PL help me to solve this problem

Comment: hello PL help me to find out

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me

```
<?php 
$vnkings_cat_id = get_cat_id( single_cat_title("",false) );
$categories = get_categories(
array('child_of' => $vnkings_cat_id,'hide_empty' => 0,'orderby' => 'id', 'order' => 'ASC',)); 
if(!empty($categories)){ ?>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach($categories as $cat){
        if('Uncategorized' != $cat->name){ ?>
            <li><a  href="<?php echo get_category_link($cat->term_id); ?>"  ><?php echo $cat->name; ?></a></li>
        <?php } } ?>      
    </ul>
<?php } else { ?>
    <ul>
        <li class="cat"><a href="<?php echo get_category_link($vnkings_cat_id); ?>"><?php echo get_cat_name($vnkings_cat_id); ?></a></li>
    </ul>
<?php } ?>
```

Tutorial: 
http://vnkings.com/hien-danh-muc-con-khi-vao-danh-muc-cha-wordpress.html

Comment: <pre>category first
 -first sub cat
  --second sub cat
   ---sub cat1
   ---sub cat2
  --third sub cat
   --- sub cat1
   --- sub cat3 </pre>
this nice code but when i click on "first sub cat" at that display only "second sub cat" and "third sub cat" not "sub cat1", "sub cat2" etc.. in your code display all... i want only "first sub cat" and "second sub cat"